# The child(wySprite, x) is already attached to another parent(wySprite, xx), skip addChild

Tags: android, cocoa

Hi I am using Wiengine for making my game and I am getting this error
The child(wySprite, x) is already attached to another parent(wySprite, xx), skip addChild

Can any one let me know how this error can be resolved

Answer (score 1):

It means the sprite already has a parent node. If you see this error, generally you have some wrong logic in your code. Well, currently WiEngine is open-sourced, you can directly debug it.  https://github.com/stubma/WiEngine